# Android Emulator access IIS Express

Tags: java, android, iis, httpurlconnection, iis-express

I have an api that I've built using visual studio and when I run it, it runs of IIS Express.
I also have an android application that I've built using Android Studio.
The android app is meant to access the api and return a JSON response, but I get a permission denied exception.

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

My android code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnGET;
    final String API = "http://localhost:1337/Test/b";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnGET = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGET);
        btnGET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DoGetTestTable().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class DoGetTestTable extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                URL url = new URL(API);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                int byteCharacter;
                String result = "";

                while((byteCharacter = is.read()) != -1){
                    result += (char) byteCharacter;
                }

                Log.d("json api", result);

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and my trace is:

```
07-01 22:59:31.736 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
07-01 22:59:31.736 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:454)
07-01 22:59:31.736 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:517)
07-01 22:59:31.736 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1108)
07-01 22:59:31.736 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:195)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
07-01 22:59:31.737 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at sentzke.jackson.apitest.MainActivity$DoGetTestTable.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:42)
07-01 22:59:31.738 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at sentzke.jackson.apitest.MainActivity$DoGetTestTable.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:34)
07-01 22:59:31.738 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
07-01 22:59:31.738 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-01 22:59:31.738 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
07-01 22:59:31.739 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
07-01 22:59:31.739 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
07-01 22:59:31.739 2429-2846/sentzke.jackson.apitest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I've tried changing local host to 10.0.2.2:1337 but that didn't work either.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

On Android of course you should use 10.0.2.2:1337, but changes are also required on IIS Express side, to change host name from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1", or blank.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7265:127.0.0.1" />
```

You can find all details in my blog post,

https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3